# Weird issue with zip/gzip files

Tags: java, zip, png, gzip

Below is a program which saves the bytes to a .png file and zips into a given name folder.

```
 byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(contents);
                    // System.out.println(new String(decodedBytes));

                    InputStream targetStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(decodedBytes);
                    int count;
                    ZipOutputStream out = new ZipOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(zipFilePath));
                    out.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(pngFile));
                    byte[] b = new byte[1024];
                    while ((count = targetStream.read(b)) > 0) {
                        out.write(b, 0, count);
                    }
                    out.flush();
                    out.close();
                    targetStream.close();
```

When i open it manually using 7 zip I see the following folder structure (c:\output\nameofzipfile.zip\nameofpng.png\nameofpng). Why is this happening? What am I doing wrong?  As per my understanding this should be the structure (c:\output\nameofzipfile.zip\nameofpng.png)

Answer (score 0):

Worked with the following code

byte[] decoded = Base64.decodeBase64(contents);
                try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(zipFilePath + amazonOrderId + zipFileName)) {
                    fos.write(decoded);
                    fos.close();
                }

```
            file = new File(destDirectory + amazonOrderId + pngFile);
            if (file.exists()) {
                file.delete();
            }
            try (OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(destDirectory + amazonOrderId + pngFile)) {
                try (InputStream in = new GZIPInputStream(
                        new FileInputStream(zipFilePath + amazonOrderId + zipFileName))) {
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[65536];
                    int noRead;
                    while ((noRead = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                        out.write(buffer, 0, noRead);
                    }
                }
            }
```